# How to globally style elements which doesn't support appearance

Tags: iphone, ios, appearance

I have learned that in iOS 5, properties that are marked with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR can be styled using appearance. Eg [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:....]. However, I seem not to be able to style all elements. UIButton, for instance, has no properties marked UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR, hence I am not able to use the above technique to style it.

My question is: How do I best style elements globally (all appearances in the application), when I cannot use appearance?

Right now I have defined some colors, fonts, shadow offsets etc. that I use many different places in my code. This allows me to change the look and behaviour of a lot of elements, but it still doesn't allow me to style all instances of a certain object with only one line of code.

**Edit**

In lack of better solutions I have created a number of [categories](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html) with simple methods as the following:

```
+ (UIButton *)customLabelWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andText:(NSString *)text;
```

Also I have found that - in combination with the described categories - [stretchable images](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/08/stretchable-images-and-buttons/) are nice and useful.

With the above I am able to style in a global-ish manner, however I am not satisfied with the result and I still hope to find a better solution

Comment: I've discovered that some things not marked with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR do, however, work with UIAppearance...some UIView properties, for example.  I won't propose that as a good answer because it might break with any release but I've found cases in this where logic triumphs over documentation.

Comment: Interesting. But I agree that it might not be the most proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about standard subclassing or factory classes, as you mentioned yourself!?
For buttons I'm using factory classes myself.

Comment: Factories for the different UI elements have definetely crossed my mind. Maybe I am too lazy, searching for something to easy, requiring unrealistically small amounts of code...

Answer (score 0):

I think a really nice solution could be the Android way of designing interfaces. Android relies on XML files to define the user interface. As a matter of fact, I'm working on a library that aims to give the projects I'm working on much the same capabilities. It's still a work in progress / experiment and as such really messy code (***you have been warned!***), but it might give you some ideas.

An example project can be downloaded here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6487838/WSLayoutManager.zip

Experiment a bit with the XML files by adding controls. Create custom control classes and instantiate them from the XML file, etc... It's fun stuff :)

Comment: Thanks for an answer providing a nice alternative. I have downloaded your sample project and it looks very interesting. However, I have been working with WPF and XAML-files and I kinda prefer the IB-way combined with programmatically styling my elements in some way, which I am searching to improve right now.